# rsyslogd-3000: omazuremds error at connect(). errno=No such file or directory

Tags: linux, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-log-analytics

I'm receiving the following error after cloning a Linux VM from one region to another:

```
rsyslogd-3000: omazuremds error at connect(). errno=No such file or directory
```

The source VM was connected to the OMS workspace in the other region. Since cloning, I have stopped any OMS related services on the box but the error persists.

Are there any other files/services I should remove to stop this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate with [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/869280/how-to-stop-certain-processes-from-polluting-the-messages-log) and read [more](https://github.com/Azure/azure-linux-extensions/issues/341)

Comment: How are you cloning the machine?